# Database Row Locking

Tags: database, concurrency

My C# program is doing the following (pseudo code):

```
START TRANSACTION READ COMMITTED
Select isOriginal, * from myTable where tnr = x;
//Record found?
Yes:
  //isOriginal? 
  Yes:
    update myTable set is_active = 0 where tnr = x;
  No:
    delete from myTable where tnr = x;
  //Do some simple logic on the values
  Insert into myTable (newvalues)
No:
  return record_not_found;
END TRANSACTION
```

However, when I start two instances of my program and both edit the same record at the same time two records are inserted as they both find the record in the select query.

What should happen is that the first transaction finds the record and inserts a new row while the second transaction returns a record not found.

How can I fix this? Put my transaction to serializable? Check the return value of update/delete? What's the best way?

*Edit*:

It should work on Sybase, Oracle & SQL Server.

Comment: Are you positive they are editing at the same time?  Remember that database time things very, very acurately just so you don't run into record locks.  they will also make one of the processes wait a random amout of time before attempting the transaction again.

Comment: Just as a recommendation and good programming practive, never `SELECT *`.  List out all column names you need, even if it is the entire table.  You never know when this table will be modified by another developer.

Comment: 3 different DB versions: sybase, oracle & sql server. Select * is just there to show the idea, I do request the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL You will need to look at `NOLOCK` and `ROWLOCK`
`NOLOCK` tells SQL Server to ignore any type of locks and read directly from the actual tables.  The pro is it has great performance, the con is in this way you are circumventing a locked system.  ROWLOCK on the other hand asks SQL Server to use row-level locks.  Performance does hinder with rowlock so you need to determine if you need to lock on `UPDATES` / `DELETES`

In your case `SELECT isOriginal, * FROM myTable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE tnr=x`

Then `UPDATE myTable WITH (ROWLOCK) SET is_active=0 WHERE tnr=x`

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what db you are using you could setup a lock field in the db.

where each concurrent thread has a pid or thread id or at least a unique timestamp
just do a

```
update myTable set lock = <pid> where pid = null limit 1;

select isOriginal, * from myTable where lock = <pid>
```